# dynamically pass in template to polymer-element

Tags: polymer

I have been trying create a polymer-element that generates a ul list based on an ajax request and then renders the "li" elements based on templates that can somehow be passsed in.

It's basically an attempt to make a polymer rebuild of the 'select2' library for autocompletion.

So, the base template I have so far looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="auto-complete" attributes="url_base item_template">
<aj-ax id="xhr" url="{{url_base}}" params="{}" handle_as="json" on-ajax-response="{{handle_res}}" on-ajax-error="{{handle_err}}"></aj-ax>
    <input id="eingabe" type="text" on-keyup="{{process_request}}" on-blur="{{hide_dropdown}}"/>
    <div id="dropdown" hidden?="{{hide}}">
      <ul>
        <template repeat="{{i in items}}">
          <li> i.text 
             <!--
                   the process_request handler makes the ajax request and sets 
                   the "items" and un-hides the dropdown.
                   the above works, but I want to make it more generic so that 
                   you can pass in a template that reads the item model such as
                   <template ref="{{item_template}}" bind></template> 
                   where item_template is the ID of a template in some outside 
                   scope
              -->
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
</polymer-element >
    </div>
```

I've also tried to make a base auto-complete.html polymer-element and then extend it based on the auto-complete type...but to no avail.

Any thoughts, ideas?

I want to stick to declarative methods if possible and avoid having to build the DOM elements myself with document.createElement

Is that even possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a cool approach to do this actually!

http://jsbin.com/hesejipeha/2/edit

The main idea is that you conditionally render the your template once you've injected any child templates into the shadow DOM (and thus made it possible to call them by ref in scope!)

Comment: Wow, that's really nice! I made a different version that doesn't require the ids to be set by the user of the element: http://jsbin.com/tisaje/28/edit?html,output